# I am looking for a solution to style.background

Tags: javascript, string, ecmascript-6

I would like to create "interactive background". When I move mouse, background will be changing. 
I tried using `object.style.background = "rgb(".hex_a.",".hex_b.",".hex_c.")";`
Obviously, it could not work.

```
const paragrapf = document.getElementById("content");
const namebox = document.getElementById("namebox");
const colorbox = document.getElementById("colorbox");
const hashbox = document.getElementById("hashbox");
document.onmousemove = function(e){
    var hex_a = e.clientX;
    var hex_b = e.clientY;
    var hex_c = e.clientX;
    colorbox.style.background = "rgb("hex_a", "hex_b", "hex_c")";
}
```

In `colorbox.style.background = "rgb("hex_a", "hex_b", "hex_c")";`

I tried adding dots between values. And I tried adding values without "quotation marks".
I even added directly values in places intended for nub 0-255.

Comment: don't put `hex_a` etc in quotes ...you wnat the value of the variable, not a string - oh, wait, you don't know how to concatenate strings in javascript, that's the problem

Comment: `"rgb("+hex_a+", "+hex_b+", "+hex_c+")";` or `\`"rgb(${hex_a}, ${hex_b}, ${hex_c})"\``;

Comment: Try using `colorbox.style.background = "#"+(hex_a).toString(16)+(hex_b).toString(16)+(hex_c).toString(16);`

Comment: @user2932057 That's good alternative. Thanks for you time ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you support string interpolation:

```
colorbox.style.background = `rgb(${hex_a}, ${hex_b}, ${hex_c})`;
```

Else:

```
colorbox.style.background = 'rgb(' + hex_a + ', ' + hex_b + ', ' + hex_c + ')';
```

Also, have in mind that `clientX` and `clientY` might(and most definately will in your case) return values higher than 255, which will cause you problems when using them in the `rgb` function.

You have to do some kind of mapping to a range. You can read more here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/clientX

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution is to concatenate:

```
colorbox.style.background = "rgb(" + hex_a + ", " + hex_b + ", " + hex_c + ")";
```